# Angular 8 ngx-bootstrap modal No component factory found

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, angular8

I have a module which looks something like:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    EmployeeRoutingModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    ListEmployeeComponent,
    EmployeeDialogComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    EmployeeService,
    BsModalService,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    EmployeeDialogComponent,
  ]
})
export class EmployeeModule {
}
```

And it is imported into the app module like so

```
{
  path: 'employee',
  loadChildren: './employee/employee.module#EmployeeModule'
},
```

within the `app.routing.ts`.

When I try and use `EmployeeDialogComponent` in my `EmployeeModule` it keeps giving off the error

```
ERROR Error: No component factory found for EmployeeDialogComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

If I add it to a module (let's call it `SharedModule`) the same way that is loaded at app run time (in the `app.module.ts` file) it works. It seems to be something about using it lazily.

What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Here is an example of minimal version of a modal that won't work:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {BsModalRef} from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'modal-content',
  template: `
    <div class="modal-body text-center">
      <p class="lead mb-5">{{ message }}</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-secondary mr-5" (click)="decline()" >{{ btnNoText }}</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" (click)="confirm()" >{{ btnYesText }}</button>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ConfirmEmployeeModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() result = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  message = 'Are you sure?';
  btnNoText = 'No';
  btnYesText = 'Yes';

  constructor(public bsModalRef: BsModalRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  confirm(): void {
    this.result.emit(true);
    this.bsModalRef.hide();
  }

  decline(): void {
    this.result.emit(false);
    this.bsModalRef.hide();
  }
}
```

I have a component within the module `ListEmployeeComponent` which contains a function like so:

```
import {
  Component,
  NgZone,
  ElementRef,
  OnInit,
  ViewContainerRef,
  PipeTransform,
  Pipe,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {DialogService, BuiltInOptions} from "ngx-bootstrap-modal";
//import { EmployeeDialogComponent } from '../employee-dialog/employee-dialog.component';
import {EmployeeService} from "../employee.service";
import {LocalStorageUtilityService, NotificationService} from "../../common/common.services";
import * as _ from 'lodash';
//import { NotifyDialogComponent } from '../../common/dialog/notify-dialog/notify-dialog.component';
import {UserService} from "../../common/user.service";
import {ConfirmModalComponent} from "../../common/confirm-modal/confirm-modal.component";
import {BsModalService} from "ngx-bootstrap/modal";
import {EmployeeDialogComponent} from "../employee-dialog/employee-dialog.component";
import {ConfirmEmployeeModalComponent} from "../confirm-employee-modal/confirm-modal.component";

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'list-employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list-employee.component.css']
})
export class ListEmployeeComponent {
  constructor(
    private modalService: BsModalService,
    public _dialogService: DialogService,
    public _companyService: EmployeeService,
    public _notificationService: NotificationService,
    private userService: UserService,
  ) {
  }

  showAddEmployeeDialog = () => {
    this.modalService.show(ConfirmEmployeeModalComponent, {}).content.result.subscribe((details: any) => {
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show the code for how do you use `EmployeeDialogComponent` in `EmployeeModule` please?

Comment: @ysf I added another modal, but I just copied this modal from my shared folder and renamed it and tried the same thing and it won't work, so that is a minimal reproducable copy

Comment: well, i wanted to see the code where you open the modal. because that's part where the error occurs.

Comment: @ysf addeed a stripped down version of the component that calls the modal

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i managed to reproduce your issue in [this repo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpgp45?file=src%2Femployee%2Femployee.module.ts) and adding `ModalModule.forRoot()` to `EmployeeModule` imports will fixes the error.

i had a similar problem with `MatDialog`, such that when i wanted to use a component from a lazy loaded module in an already created instance of `MatDialog` (which is an injectable) i was getting the same error. Then i noticed that the service should be initialized from scratch when to be used with lazy-loaded components. And something similar is happening in your case as well.

according to [docs](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals) `ModalModule` is imported with `forRoot()` like;

```js
// RECOMMENDED
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
// or
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ModalModule.forRoot(),...]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

which means a global singleton instance of `BsModalService` is created and used across whole app. And it doesn't have any knowledge of lazy-loaded components at initialization.

So, solution would be to initialize a new instance for lazy-loaded module such that adding `ModalModule.forRoot()` to `EmployeeModule` imports will fix the error.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    EmployeeRoutingModule,
    ModalModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [
    EmployeeDialogComponent,
    ListEmployeeComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    BsModalService,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    EmployeeDialogComponent,
  ]
})
export class EmployeeModule {}
```

however be aware that this will create a new instance of `BsModalService` dedicated to `EmployeeModule` and it won't be aware of any other context outside of it as well as any outside context won't be aware of it. which in simpler terms means you can't interact with this particular dialog (such as closing it) anywhere else except `EmployeeModule` context.

Comment: Thanks makes sense now "which means a global singleton instance of BsModalService is created and used across whole app. And it doesn't have any knowledge of lazy-loaded components at initialization." Is this more ngx-bootstrap problem or just how angular works?

Comment: i think it is more like ngx-bootstrap problem because in my case i had the problem when i used an already injected instance of `MatDialog` through a global service. And when i injected `MatDialog` in that particular component the problem is gone. i didn't need to import any module etc.

Comment: That's weird, I know it isn't supposed to know about instances outside of it, but the old modal that's included in the shared module works just fine still, which is very weird (I'm a angular noob so almost everything is weird to me), could forroot be providing the rooted instance of the module?

Comment: actually that's not weird that's how angular injector works. it is explained [here](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection) in detail.

Comment: Ah ok good to yeah, the forroot takes an instance of the parent injector, I think I remember somewhere in the docs that it takes a copy of the parent injector, so that's probably why, it is making a whole new instance of ModalModule etc etc

Comment: exactly. and i just checked out if this is a ngx-bootstrap problem or not and found [this](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/2356) apparently this has been a known issue for almost 2 years without any progress :/ and they propose same solution over there as well.

Comment: Typical, I'm not sure how I didn't find that in my Googling, thanks for all the help!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't need to do that priop to angular 8! has this been reported to `ngx-bs` ?

Comment: I wonder, does it behave differently if you declare it in a lazy loaded component?

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the solution was adding the following in the module:

```
import {  NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
imports: [
    NgbModule
]
```

Comment: This question is asking about ngx-bootstrap.